# Jade: Loop Through Every 4 Elements, Changing Class

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I am building a step sequencer, and I would like to group each 4 elements in a sub-group, using Jade.  So far, I have only been able to get every *nth* element with the desired class, but I know there's a way to do this.  The only constraint being I need to keep track of the current index in the loop (from 1 to 32) so that I can properly add unique `id`s to each `input` element.

My code so far, which strangely styles every `n+2` elements:

```
- for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++)
                - if (i % 4 === 0 || altGroup % 2 === 0)
                  - stepClass="step even"
                  - altGroup++
                - else
                  - stepClass="step"
                input(type="checkbox", class = "#{stepClass}", id = "channel#{index}-step#{i}")
                label(for = "channel#{index}-step#{i}")
                  span.hook ^
```

[See the pen here](http://codepen.io/srsgores/pen/DufqI)

Comment: Just a note that fenced backticks (i.e. `\`\`\``) aren't supported by Stack Overflow's Markdown parser, you need to indent the code using 4 spaces (or selecting the code and pressing Ctrl+K).

Comment: Not completely sure I understand but is this [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yKcEr) what you were after? And by sub-group do you want them within another DOM element, if so let me know and I'll adjust the pen.

Comment: Yes, thanks!  I can't believe I was so close!  Go ahead and update.

Comment: No problem. Sorry it took me so long to get to this today, been one of those days. I'll add an answer below. I've changed a bit of the logic but hopefully it is as you required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the exchange above I have separated each of the sub-groups into a `span` element with the class `sub-group` to make it clearer. Please see updated [CodePen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IFmAz).

The key logic is summarized below:

```
- for (var i = 0; i < steps/4; i++)
    - if (altGroup % 2 == 0)
        - stepClass = "step"
    - else
        - stepClass = "step even"
    span.sub-class
        - for (var j=0; j < groupSize; j++)
            input(type="checkbox", class = "#{stepClass}", id = "channel#{index}-step#{i}")
            label(for = "channel#{index}-step#{i}")
                span.hook ^
        - altGroup ++;
```

Note: that I have assumed that the group size is a constant and added this as a variable.